# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' Instagram

Tags: python

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/Myprofile/'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
followers = re.search('"edge_followed_by":{"count":(\d*)}', soup.prettify()).group(1)
```

Returning:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' Instagram
```

Comment: There were no matches for the regex search, so you get `None`, which has no `group` attribute.

Comment: Don't simply assume that a match is successful -- test your assumptions. At the very least, catch the error when your assumptions are false.